# gem local install conundrum: cicrular loop installing gems

Tags: rubygems

I need to install a bunch of gems onto a host that has no incoming net access.

And I seem to run into a conundrum.

```
[root@uszmpaplp005la ruby]# gem install --local rdoc-4.1.1.gem
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Error instaling rdoc-4.1.1.gem:
        rdoc requires json ~> 1.4

[root@uszmpaplp005la ruby]# gem install --local json-1.8.1.gem
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Error instaling json-1.8.1.gem:
        json requires sdoc ~> 0.3.16

[root@uszmpaplp005la ruby]# gem install --local sdoc-0.4.0.gem
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Error instaling sdoc-0.4.0.gem:
        sdoc requires rdoc ~> 4.0, < 5.0
```

Is there any way out of this dependency hell?

Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 0):

gem install will accept multiple gems on one line.  Try including them all.  Something like

```
gem install --local rdoc-4.1.1.gem json-1.8.1.gem sdoc-0.4.0.gem
```